# Having Dlookup issues. The code won't work?

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

Basically it says I am missing operators?

```
Dim descpc As String

despc = DLookup("[Description]", "[products/stock]", "[Product Code] = " & Me.cmbSource.Value)
Me.Text47.Value = despc
```

Can anyone spot anything? I'm not 100% with Dlookup so any help would be brilliant!

Thanks, Bob P

Comment: 2 things - What is the exact error message, and do you need quotes around your search for the product code: `"[Product Code] = '" & Me.cmbSource.Value & "'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dim-ing cmbSource as a string, so you'll need to enclose the value in sigle quotes to handle the string. Also, if Product Code is a number, you might get an error if you're then trying to compare a string to an integer. Try this:

```
despc = DLookup("[Description]", "[products/stock]", "[Product Code] = '" & Me.cmbSource & "'")
```